# Access text files during run time with Xamarin.Forms (on Android)?

Tags: c#, file, xamarin.forms, path

I am currently working on a project in which different text files are loaded during run time. I save the path to the file in a database, and when needed the path is loaded, the file gets opened and the contents are placed in a label. I've got everything working, except the file storage.

In my project I have a folder `Resources` in which the text files are placed. How do I access this folder from my project? All I can find online describes the storage in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`, but I can't place my stuff in there before run time, so I will need to find the path beforehand. I've also read some about internal vs external storage, but that doesn't seem to involve paths within the app.

I know that in Unity I can just use the `Resources` folder, so I've tried to apply the same logic here. Is it any similar at all?

Comment: are these files created and saved dynamically at run time?  Or are they all pre-existing at build time?

Comment: They're all pre-existing. I chose for text files because it's easier to edit between iterations as opposed to database entries.

Comment: see the linked question on reading data from resources.  Alternately, you could include them as Android Assets

Comment: It took a while, but I got it working. Thanks a lot Jason!